# T-SQL: modified CREATE TABLE script to ALTER TABLE script crashes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, alter-table, create-table

This script was generated from SQL Server Management Studio.  Why am I getting this error and how can I fix the ALTER script?  Note, that I changed the word "CREATE" to "ALTER".  So I'm guessing the CREATE syntax is slightly different from the ALTER syntax, or has less restrictions.  I'm using SQL Server 2008 Express.  I see it's telling me to end with a semicolon, but I want to make sure terminating the statement won't cause me any issues later.  If you can describe what each piece of the query does and what we're changing, bonus points awarded.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
--CREATE TABLE [dbo].[defect](
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[defect](
    [defect_id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [defect_number] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [defect_type] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [date_created] [datetime] NULL,
    [user_identified_by] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [status] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [date_modified] [datetime] NULL,
    [user_qa] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [severity] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [environment] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [user_assigned] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [project] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [target_table_affected] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [required_for_go_live] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [project_phase] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [completion_hours] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [date_migrate_prod] [datetime] NULL,
    [description] [text] NULL,
    [table_columns_affected] [text] NULL,
    [sample_data] [text] NULL,
    [action_taken] [text] NULL,
    [supp_detail_links] [text] NULL,
    [supp_detail_links_dtml] [text] NULL,
    [thread] [bigint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_defect] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [defect_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Error:

> *Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>
>   Incorrect syntax near '('.
>
>   Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 29
>
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table  expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking
>   context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a
>   semicolon.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ALTER TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE` are two totally different SQL statements that you cannot acheive by simply replacing `CREATE` with `ALTER`, so the way you generated your ALTER is wrong, what you can do is

1. you can simply generate the `ALTER` script using the `Change Script` option available in SSMS every time when you change any Table or db object.
2. Alternatively you can generate Alter scripts using VS2010(google for it as I am not gonna write this here) or any third party script generator, easily available on internet

Additionally, instead of posting SQL statements on SO for others to explain them for you, give sometime to SQL learning (at least using SQL books online, installed with SQL server).

Comment: I'm surprised how I got -2 for my question, but I earned the "Popular Question" badge for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to add a column, the syntax is

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[defect]
ADD
    [defect_id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
...
```

If you wish to change the size of a column

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[defect]
    ALTER COLUMN [completion_hours] [nvarchar](50) NULL
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx

What you could do in future is when you change the column definition on DEV, then click on the `Script Changes` button in SSMS design view and apply that script to your QA environment.

The reason why those "fancy tools" exist is because this is all a bit of a pain. If it's just a question of budget, then the Microsoft SSDT may be more to your liking  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx

Comment: We're assuming a lot from this answer.  Can you describe a little better what we're doing here, and describe what the new code would be?  Are you saying you just added the keyword "ADD" to the beginning, and that's it?

Comment: I can, but I'm not clear what it is you're trying to do. What is your starting point? Are you trying to change the structure of an existing table, or add columns to an existing one?

Comment: @MacGyver - you need to state ***specifically*** what changes you want to make to the table.  *[You can't re-include everything that's there already, so until we know what lines are real changes, we can't tell you how to change the code.  Perhaps you could check the syntax in books online as a start?]*

Comment: I have 2 databases.  DEV and QA.  I modified this table in design mode and added some columns in DEV, and now I'm getting QA to be consistent with DEV.  I am not using Red Gate SQL Compare (or any other fancy tools) for diffing between databases.  Essentially I just created a script to re-build the entire database, and I'm picking out the pieces for migration script.

Comment: @MacGuyver - If you don't use a tool to identify the changes, you need to identify them yourself.  But you can't just change pieces of the `CREATE TABLE` script to make an `ALTER TABLE` script.  As an example, make changes to a table using SQL Server Management Studio, but ask it to create a script instead of making the changes.  Then you'll have a clear example of how different the two are.

Answer (score 0):

ALTER and CREATE does not work the same as with Stored Procedures.
Use this link to understand exactly how ALTER statement on tables work.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp